# rxjs5 toPromise not working

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

In the following example `toPromise` does not work:

https://jsfiddle.net/tossp/nmf9jg32/

My code:

```
function getPostData() {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(res => res.json())
}
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'click');

var example = source.concatMap(
            e => Rx.Observable.from(getPostData()), 
            (e, res, eIndex, resIndex) => res.title);

example.subscribe({
    next: (value) => { console.log('subscribe!!!',value); },
    error: (err) => { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
    complete: () => { console.log('complete'); }
});
example.do((value)=>console.log('do!!!',value)).toPromise().then((value)=>console.log('toPromise!!!',value));
```

Comment: the promise created by `toPromise` just never gets resolved - how do you think that should happen?

Answer (score 27):

Already solved https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2536

`toPromise` is essentially `observable.last().subscribe()`

If you add `.take(1)` just before you call `toPromise` then things will start to work.

ie

```
example.do((value)=>console.log('do!!!',value)).take(1).toPromise()
```

Comment: Should also work with first() operator :)

Answer (score 14):

In newer versions you must use `take(1)` inside `pipe()`. I did this kind of code:

```
async getPromise() {

    return await example
    .pipe(take(1))
    .toPromise();

  }
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: .pipe(take(1)) made my promise work ng9.1.1 rxjs6.5.3

Comment: Thank you!!!  I was losing my mind trying to get this to work!